# Database DefaultConnectionFactory not used when executed on thread pool thread

Tags: entity-framework

I have an Asp.Net MVC 4 project using Entity Framework 5.0.

For some reason my DefaultConnectionFactory is not being called when I execute EF code from a Threadpool thread.

I setup my connection factory in the Application_Start event of my Asp.Net MVC project:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new WebConnectionFactory();
```

This runs successfully on all data access code so far.

I have a Parallel.ForEach loop with a call to some EF code.  For some reason the DefaultConnectionFactory is never hit when called.  This factory is critical for my code to execute, so the call fails (it uses its default connection string).

Any ideas why this DefaultConnectionFactory would not be called when run on a new thread?

Comment: _the DefaultConnectionFactory is never hit when called_ - do you mean that `CreateConnection` in `WebConnectionFactory` is never hit?

Comment: Yes thats correct.  I can see a breakpoint is never hit and the context is populated from what looks like the default connection string from config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the connection that you built for each call that you are wanting to use.  For example using the following code.

```
private static void UsingCustomConnection()
{
    using (var conn = Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.CreateConnection("YourDbName"))
    {
        using (var context = new YourContext(conn))
        {
            context.Destinations.Add(new Destination {Name = "Colorado"});
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to setup this in YourContext

```
public YourContext(DbConnection connection)
    : base(connection, contextOwnsConnection: false)
{
}
```

Comment: Also can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724807/entity-framework-defaultconnectionfactory-being-ignored/15124821#15124821)