# Entity Framework doesn't use defaultConnectionFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been trying to use Effort to test one of our legacy programs. I followed this guide for that: https://blog.goyello.com/2016/07/14/save-time-mocking-use-your-real-entity-framework-dbcontext-in-unit-tests/

The problem is that CreateConnection() in the EffortProviderFactory never gets called. I refer to it in the Testprojects app.config with

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="Pmt.Test.EffortProviderFactory, Pmt.Test" >
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

I try to create a product in my test method using

```
using (var model = new DBEntities())
{
    var testProd = new tblProdukte
    {
        nr_Produktnummer = "P1A000001-011"
    };
    model.tblProdukte.Add(testProd);
    model.SaveChanges();
}
```

But it connects to my sql database and uses the factory "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory", inserting that new product in my db. I read that I need to remove the connection string in my Test Projects app.config, but then my DbContext has a null connection and crashes at model.tblProdukte.Add(testProd);.

Using the following code

```
public DBBase(string nameOrConnectionString)
    :   base(Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(nameOrConnectionString), true)
```

from this Question [Entity Framework DefaultConnectionFactory being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724807/entity-framework-defaultconnectionfactory-being-ignored) seems to work, but appearantly that function is deprecated and I don't really want to change the context if theres a better way, I'd much prefere to get EF to read from my app.config.